# Установка apc на битрикс

Tags: php, debian, битрикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему не устанавливается, как устранить эту ошибку на картинке?
   `PHP Version 5.4.44-0+deb7u1
System  Linux unimann 2.6.32-042stab112.15 #1 SMP Tue Oct 20 17:22:56 MSK 2015 x86_64
Build Date  Aug 16 2015 09:52:28
Server API  CGI/FastCGI`

Делала по Ипатьеву, возникла ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем компилить когда можно просто установить готовый пакет от своего дистрибутива?

Comment: А почему на вирт.сервер не устанавливать BitrixVM, где все "искаропки"?

Comment: сайт рабочий. куда деваться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишет же, черным по белому - не найден компилятор

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

должно решить проблему

Comment: Делала по вашему, возникла ошибка ( второй скриншот)

Comment: @RRR libpcre3 и libpcre3-dev установите

Comment: apt-get install libpcre3-dev установила

Comment: а libpcre3 нет.  Вроде установился apc.Надо устанавливать ?

Answer (score 0):

Для установки apc на Debian достаточно выполнить команду

```
apt-get install php-apc
```